# CalendarView to Device Calendar Link

Tags: android, calendar

I have a CalendarView. When a date is pressed, the application opens up the device's Calendar on the particular date that was clicked:

```
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            cal.set(year,month,dayOfMonth);

            long epochMillis = cal.getTimeInMillis();

            Uri.Builder uriBuilder =  CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
            uriBuilder.appendPath("time");
            ContentUris.appendId(uriBuilder, epochMillis);
            Uri uri = uriBuilder.build();

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(uri);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

This works fine. My question is, is there a way to bring the user to the "Create Event Screen" instead of where it is currently taking me, which is a view of the entire month with the selected day highlighted? I would like them to be able to click on a date in my CalendarView and be taken to a screen on the device's calendar that lets them add appointments to the selected date. Wondering if anyone knows what the uri for that screen is? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Two Things.

1. I was appending "time" to my URI. This will simply open the Calendar up to the specific time that I specify when the intent is launched. In order to open an event screen for a specific date, I need to append, "events" instead.
2. When I created the intent, I used ACTION_VIEW. Instead, I need ACTION_INSERT. I then set the data of the Intent using my new URI, which includes "events" and then specify a start time, which is the specific date that I want:

   ```
       calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
       cal = Calendar.getInstance();

       cal.set(year,month,dayOfMonth);

       long epochMillis = cal.getTimeInMillis();

       Uri.Builder uriBuilder =  CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
       uriBuilder.appendPath("events");

       Uri uri = uriBuilder.build();

       Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
       i.setData(uri);
       i.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, epochMillis);
       startActivity(i);

   }});
   ```